# Arduino / DigiSpark / ATtiny85 - Receiving and parsing several pieces of data

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

i'm trying to make a digispark to work with bluetooth and NeoPixel, while i had success into making it go on and off i would like to expand on it.

I have used the Robin2 example 5 method to reciece, and parse my data in order to get the leds color the way i want.

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=396450.msg2727728#msg2727728
this is the code in my case - the original is in the link above

```
void loop() {
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();
  if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
            // this temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
            //   because strtok() used in parseData() replaces the commas with \0
  parseData();
  strip.setBrightness(xB);
  controlLed();  
  newData = false;
  }

}


void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;
 
    while (bluetooth.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = bluetooth.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            } else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }   else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}


void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars, ",");      // get the first part - the string
    eFx = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");      // get the first part - the string
    rC1 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer
 
    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    gC1 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    bC1 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    xS = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    xB = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer




}





void controlLed() {
         colorWipe(strip.Color(rC1, gC1, bC1), xS);
         colorWipe(strip.Color(20, 50, 100), 50);
}
```

now i have some issues, as the ATtiny85 memory is not that great i ran into issues when i try to send longer strings, basically i want to send all these:

```
int eFx = 1;
int rC1 = 100;
int gC1 = 100;
int bC1 = 100;
int xS = 20;
int xB = 100;
int rC2 = 5;
int gC2 = 50;
int bC2 = 200;
```

but when i try to parse it with the strtokIndx method above the digispark stops working (when i add more to what is already shown in the code ex above) i guess it's due to memory issues.

i understand part of the code,but not well enough to expand it in the direction that i want.

Right now the way it works is that when i send via BTooth info in this format asd<1,24,23,54,...,>qwe the recvWithStartEndMarkers () will grab all there is between < > and store it (?) in receivedChars

then i'm not sure why and how parseData() grabs this string and not something else, is it because of the function in the loop?

```
  strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
  parseData();
```

Well, i want to try to make this process go at it again, to recieve another string under [ ] and not < > and parseData2() (maybe) on receivedChars2 to get my last 3 INTs (color values for NeoPixel) parsed and stored in order to use them without having the digispark crash out of memory

The first step would be to change the

```
void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
```

to detect also de diffrence between < and [ and run the proper code in order to store either in receivedChars or receivedChars2

not sure how to do that, also i'm not sure if this would be useful and would solve my memory issues.

any thoughts?

here is the full code i'm running

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h> // NeoPixel Lib
#include <SoftSerial.h>  // Serial Lib
#define LED_PIN    2
#define LED_COUNT 30

SoftSerial bluetooth(4, 5); // RX TX
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

const byte numChars = 42;
char receivedChars[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars];
boolean newData = false;

int eFx = 1;
int rC1 = 100;
int gC1 = 100;
int bC1 = 100;
int xS = 20;
int xB = 100;
int rC2 = 5;
int gC2 = 50;
int bC2 = 200;


void setup() {

  bluetooth.begin (9600);
  strip.begin();           // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
  strip.show();            // Turn OFF all pixels ASAP

}


void loop() {
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();
  if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
            // this temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
            //   because strtok() used in parseData() replaces the commas with \0
  parseData();
  strip.setBrightness(xB);
  controlLed();  
  newData = false;
  }

}


void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;
 
    while (bluetooth.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = bluetooth.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            } else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }   else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}


void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars, ",");      // get the first part - the string
    eFx = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");      // get the first part - the string
    rC1 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer
 
    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    gC1 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    bC1 = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    xS = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    xB = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer




}





void controlLed() {
         colorWipe(strip.Color(rC1, gC1, bC1), xS);
         colorWipe(strip.Color(20, 50, 100), 50);
}

void controlLed2() {

         colorWipe(strip.Color(rC2, gC2, bC2), xS);
} 

void colorWipe(uint32_t color, int wait) {
  
  for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) { // For each pixel in strip...
    strip.setPixelColor(i, color);         //  Set pixel's color (in RAM)
    strip.show();                          //  Update strip to match
    delay(wait);                           //  Pause for a moment
  }
}
```

Comment: re:  then i'm not sure why and how parseData() grabs this string and not something else, is it because of the function in the loop?

Because it is dealing with global variables.  What's in receivedChars gets copied into tempChars in loop and all that is global.  Google "C++ variable scope" to learn about global variables vs local variables.

Comment: You're on the right track with the rest.  You need your if statement to check for < or [ and then another one that sets some other variable depending on which one it is.  At the end you test that variable to decide which parser to call.

Comment: Thx Delta_G, i've also discovered that the memory on my DigiSpark won't allow me to do much more, i've managed to figure out a way into adding an effect another way around. I won't be able to get more color codes, but i can flip the values of the colors that i'm sending among themselves. Still the question will remain as i want to solve the mistery as well as in the future i might go for a more advanced board. Now i'm strugling with another way more simple question.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983799/arduino-c-if-int-value-x-then

Comment: Get an UNO.  It can do a lot more and doesn't cost much for a clone

Comment: i have one, the big issue for me is size, i need to put all the components into a shoe :)), after the size there are a few more things to consider, digispark was the choice the filled most needs. The shape and the fact that i can just plug it into an off the market 5v batery were the tipping points and made it a winner. After i finish this project i'll have to reconsider my take on all of these.

Comment: Get a nano then.  You can get a 328P on a pretty small board.

Comment: Or a pro mini, they are even smaller.