# Arduino / C++ - IF INT value = X Then

Tags: c++, arduino

i have an INT in my arduino code that i constantly update it's value and i want to check the value and compare it to static values and run IF statments out of it. Something like this

```
INT = 3

If (int = 1) { run1() }
If (int = 2) { run2() }
If (int = 3) { run3() }
```

the above example just overwrites the original INT value

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. Use `==` to compare.

Comment: `=` would be an assignment. For a comparison you need `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ `=` is the assignment operator. Please use `==` to compare:

```
int i = 3;

if (i == 1) { run1(); }
if (i == 2) { run2(); }
if (i == 3) { run3(); }
```

Also note the lowercase `if` and that `int` is a keyword which you can't use as variable name.

You might want to check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) - it has some useful resources for beginners.